# Why will it not echo "$d" answer

Tags: bash

I need the script to output the result, but `echo "$d"` does not output anything.   I made the *ciphertext.gz* earlier in the script and the `$fil` is *ciphertext.gz*.  Bash script:

```
echo "Fil: ciphertext.gz"

a="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ"

[[ "${*/-d/}" != "" ]] &&
echo "Usage: $0 [-d]" && exit 1
m=${1:+-}
m=-

t=$fil 
printf "Nøgle 'eks. ABCDE': "
read -r k
k=$(echo "$k" | tr [a-vx-z] [A-VX-Z] )
printf "\n"
for ((i=0;i<${#t};i++)); do
    p1=${a%%${t:$i:1}*}
    p2=${a%%${k:$((i%${#k})):1}*}
    d="${d}${a:$(((${#p1}${m:-+}${#p2})%${#a})):1}"
done
echo "$d"
```

Comment: What output is expected for what input?

Comment: what are you doing ? what is in ciphertext.gz ?

Comment: There is text inside ciphertext.gz, i need the text from ciphertext.gz to be decrypted and result to show, but with echo "$d" it leaves the screen blank

Comment: Indentation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) would do you good!

Comment: maybe you wanted content in t `t=$(gzip -cd "$fil")`

Comment: `set -x` to see how that `d=...` line is being evaluated. `echo $d` is working, but your assignment to `d=` isn't working. Maybe https://shellcheck.net will show you a useful error message. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Extended comments, (not really an answer, since it's unclear what the code should do):

1. This is wrong:

   ```
   m=${1:+-}
   m=-
   ```

   ...since it has the same effect as:

   ```
   m=-
   ```
2. This reads **one** line from standard input:

   ```
   read -r k
   ```

   ...which, unless *ciphertext* is only one line long, probably
   defeats the purpose of the next eight lines of code.  Even if
   standard input was `unzip < ciphertext.gz |`, it would only decode
   the first line of *ciphertext*.

   Wrap the `for` in an appropriate `while read k` loop.